# Receiving "none" type data instead of object from MySQL to PyCharm

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

I am working with log in activity in PyCharm(Python), While calling some data from MySQL database like email and password I am getting none type error as following.

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
> if info['email']==username and info['password']==password:

As per my investigation some problem is in following code.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `logininfo` WHERE email=%s AND password=%s", (username, password))
            info = cursor.fetchone()
            print(info)
            if info['email']==username and info['password']==password:
```

My whole pyCharm code is as following

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect,session, url_for
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
import MySQLdb

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "1234353234"

app.config["MYSQL_HOST"] = "127.0.0.1"
app.config["MYSQL_USER"] = "root"
app.config["MYSQL_PASSWORD"] = "password"
app.config["MYSQL_DB"] = "login"

db = MySQL(app)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
            username = request.form['username']
            password = request.form['password']
            cursor = db.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `logininfo` WHERE email=%s AND password=%s", (username, password))
            info = cursor.fetchone()
            print(info)
            if info['email']==username and info['password']==password:
                return "Logged in Successfully"
            else:
                return "Please register first!"
    return render_template("login.html")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with pycharm. That's just a code editor

Comment: According to the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-fetchone.html), your query did not return a match -- "This method retrieves the next row of a query result set and returns a single sequence, or None if no more rows are available."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When this query

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM `logininfo` WHERE email=%s AND password=%s", (username, password))
info = cursor.fetchone()
```

doesn't find a matching row, it returns None (null in Python). that makes info['email'] fail because there is no object to check.

So you have to change your code to:

```
        if info and info['email']==username and info['password']==password:
            return "Logged in Successfully"
        else:
            return "Please register first!"
```

Comment: @GaneshKadam Please don't forget to accept the answer if it worked. Thanks!

Comment: There is a checkbox to the left of the answer below the vote counter. Click it and it will turn green indicating this answer was accepted. For a more thorough explanation, check out the meta site, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work